# org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I dont understand why I am getting this error on the save below.  Any clue?

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [com.test.DataException]: Getter for property 'id' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

**Code**

```
try {
            DataException dataException = new DataException();
            dataException.tenant = job.tenant;
            dataExceptionRepository.save(dataException);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {

        }
```

**DataException.java**

```
@Entity
public class DataException {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tenantId")
    public Tenant tenant;

    public String sourceSystem;
    public String objectType;
    public String objectId;
    public String description;
    public Date jobDate;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

**Stack Trace**

```
 org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [com.test.DataException]: Getter for property 'id' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:823) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:699) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation$DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.getPropertyValue(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:225) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.getId(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:84) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractEntityInformation.isNew(AbstractEntityInformation.java:53) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:353) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:318) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260) ~[spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_17]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [na:1.7.0_17]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [na:1.7.0_17]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_17]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292) [na:1.7.0_17]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_17]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_17]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_17]
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
```

Comment: There should be more to the stacktrace. Post it.

Comment: I don't know what I'm supposed to do with that. Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: There you go I believe that is what you want.

Comment: Your id is `Long` and not `long`. When constructing the object your `Long` is `null` leading to a `NullPointerException` when autoboxing to a `long` hence your exception. Either change the id field to be a `long` or make your getter/setters for `Long`.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Your getter & setter need to be `Long` rather than `long`

Comment: I had several related issues, the first was the lack of a AUTOINCREMENT and then the "long" x "Long" issue. Thanks !

Comment: I could not have figured this out in a million years. Thank you!